# Prove that the following polynomial is negative on $[-1,1]$

Tags: calculus, inequality, polynomials

Let $c \in [-1,1]$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$, show that:
$$
-m + (2+m) c - (2+m) c^{1+m} + m c^{2+m} \leq 0
$$

I have proven it for $c \in [-1,0]$ and $m \in 2\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that
$$-m + (2+m) c - (2+m) c^{1+m} + m c^{2+m} =(c-1)\left(m(c^{m+1}+1)-2(c^m+\dots+c)\right).$$
So it suffices to show that for $c \in [-1,1)$ and for $m>0$,
$$\frac{c^{m+1}+1}{2}\geq \frac{c^m+\dots+c}{m}.$$
The LHS is $\geq 0$ and the RHS is $c(1-c^m)/(1-c)\leq 0$ for $c\in [-1,0]$.

Hence we may assume that $c\in(0,1)$. We show this last part by induction on $m$. For $m=1$ the inequality holds.
If $m\geq 1$ then
$$\frac{c^{m+1}+\dots+c}{m+1}=\frac{mc\frac{c^{m}+\dots+c}{m}+c}{m+1}\leq \frac{mc\frac{c^{m+1}+1}{2}+c}{m+1}\stackrel{?}{\leq}\frac{c^{m+2}+1}{2}$$
which holds because $c\to c^{m+2}$ is convex in $(0,1)$ and 
$$c^{m+2}\geq (m+2)(c-1)+1.$$

Comment: I understand the hint and see the logic of why this last inequality should hold, I'm looking for a proof but I should be able to find it.

Comment: @HolyMonk See my edited answer.

Comment: nice answer, thanks!

Comment: I thought I had it but I am struggling with the last step of the proof now, could you explain it in more detail?

Comment: @HolyMonk Convexity implies that the function $c^{m+2}$ stays above the tangent lines. In particular $y=(m+2)(c-1)+1$ which is the tangent line at $1$.

Comment: Agreed, but how does this imply the last inequality?

Comment: @HolyMonk In the last inequality subtract the LHS from the RHS. Then you obtain $$(c^{m+2}-[(m+2)c-m-1])/(2(m+1))$$ which is $\geq 0$.

Comment: Okay got it! Thanks man!